# Webservers: When did www.domain.net/dir/file.html first not point to $WWWROOT/dir/file.html but to something virtualized?

Tags: history, internet

If I'm not mistaken, the first webserver simply served all files and directories in a certain local directory (WWWROOT) in the identical hierarchy at a certain domain. This is in line how e.g. an FTP server acts. By contrast, nowadays many websites typically use generated pages served at arbitrary, well-designed points at the directory hierarchy below the domain.

When was the first time that the hierarchy presented by the webserver was virtualized like that?

Edit: I'm not talking so much about dynamically created content. CGI is indeed very old, but it used to be an actual files sitting in an actual location below WWWROOT and you would "call" it by adding that relative location to the domain the webserver was serving.

I'm more talking about the kind of URL schemes that e.g. Django talks about here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/ : As a part of setting up a website, you think of a URL scheme such that it is easily readable and then the webserver will server the files accordingly. They typically have nothing at all to do with files in a webroot.

As an example, take the URL that is currently displayed in my browser: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/15162/edit Is there somewhere a "15162" directory, containing a "edit" directory, containing an "index.html"? Most probably not. There probably isn't even a "posts" directory and all contents comes from a database, the pages being dynamically created.

That is great and gives you a high degree of flexibility, but that could only come about after someone realized: "Hey, I know www.domain.net/dir/file.html currently always serves $WWWROOT/dir/file.html, but in the end it is just a request to which a program (the webserver) needs to give a response which might, but need to be a verbatim copy of a file on disk." I'm referring to that idea of solving the problem right at the core, the webserver, and not by placeing a CGI script or Java applet somewhere in the directory structure below the webroot and then serving that in a special way.

Comment: I'll have to go back to the source, but I believe the very first CERN server allowed directory paths to be MAPped and have a REDIRECT. So it was always available. I used it in about 1993

Comment: Do you mean the ability to serve e.g. "/foo/bar" at `http://site/bar` and "/baz" at `http://site/baz`?

Comment: CGI has been around since 1993: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Comment: Not sure what you really mean by "virtualized." Are you asking about dynamic content? Are you asking about a web server where URL paths are not always simply transformed into file paths on the server? Are you asking about "virtual hosting?" (see Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's answer, below)

Comment: (Statically) generated pages placed at "arbitrary" generated URLs are quite old, I remember implementing this by hand with a `Makefile` and a bunch of scripts somewhere in the 90s. This works with any webserver, the magic is in the generation scripts.

Comment: Not sure when it first happened but the [great book _Database Backed Web Sites_ (Greenspun)](https://philip.greenspun.com/wtr/dead-trees/) promoted virtualizing the entire hierarchy (indirecting URL components through a map in a database) at a fairly early date (1997) - none of the other books I read in that timeframe discussed anything like it.

Comment: Depending on your perspective, it was supported from day 1 with 404 errors, etc.

Comment: The [original HTTP spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) included [index searches](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/Search.html) (known as "virtual documents").  That wasn't CGI for the simple reason that CGI hadn't been invented yet, but doesn't fit your URL criteria.

Comment: @Kelvin Sherlock: I'm less interested in dynamically generated pages, but more in URL schemes that don't correspond to a directory structure (even if the latter implies the former). While the searching could in theory be used for such a URL scheme, as far as I am aware they were only ever used to pass parameters to the page generation, not as a hierarchical path to the generated page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Writing Apache Modules with Perl and C (Doug MacEachern; Lincoln Stein, 1998, O'Reilly Media, Inc., 1999):

> If you wanted to extend the functionality of the [CERN httpd] web server -- for example, to hook it up to a bibliographic database of scientific papers -- you had to modify the server's source code and recompile.
>
> ...
>
> The earliest web API that we know of was built into the Plexus web server, written by Tony Sanders of BSDI. Plexus was a 100 percent pure Perl server that did almost everything that web servers of the time were expected to do. Written entirely in Perl Version 4, Plexus allowed the webmaster to extend the server by adding new source files to be compiled and run on an as-needed basis.

CERN httpd was first released in 1991.  Plexus was released in early 1993. So it's reasonable to say that 1991 or 1992 someone did modify the CERN httpd to use virtualized URLs.

Comment: Are we sure that format was used? It used to be common to use query parameters for this - e.g. `/cgi-bin/get-paper.pl?paper_id=12345678`

Comment: Thanks to the wayback machine, I managed to dig up a copy of plexus as well as the Indiana University perl http server that it was based on.  Most do use ?parameters but there is a [weather module](https://github.com/ksherlock/plexus/blob/httpd/httpd/wx.pl) which takes a url like `/wx/us-city/IND` I don't believe it actually works, in it's current state (the weather part, that is), but 1) it was possible at the time and 2) people thought of doing it at the time.

Answer (score 4):

I'll have to look up the exact date but it was definitely pre-CGI. Very early on in the development of the web I wrote my own web server in perl that had not root directory.  It would take the requested path and do a table lookup to find which subroutine should serve that "tree".  I took it very much to heart that the path requested by a browser could be viewed as an abstract token.  It may look like a file system path the web server did not have to ever map it to any directory or file in the system at all to serve the request.

This web server was the first at the Computer Science department at the University of British Columbia and quite possibly one of the first in the entire province.

The main problem with this approach was that modules for serving content (whether dynamic or static) could not be shared with other web servers.  When the idea of a "Common Gateway Interface" was proposed I became heavily involved in the standardization effort as my web server was effectively a "CGI-only" web server.

Answer (score 1):

In the early days a webserver did not know or care which hostname it served, it just served files (and optionally allowed for running external CGI scripts as the webserver itself couldn't).  So, a single web root on disk for all hostnames recognized by the underlying host.

Also the `http://xxx/~user` syntax allowed for users to host their own pages in their home directory.  This was naturally dynamically mapped.

The need for separate web roots came with the ability to support multiple non-identical hosts by a single web server which was added with HTTP/1.1 (which came out in 1999) - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting

Comment: That's the perfect answer (beside nitpicking about directory links to move it somewhere). Only the need of dynamic access to different virtual servers over the same address (IP&port) makes dynamic selecting the root directory a thing. There are no virtual servers without a supporting protocol feature While HTTP 1.0 did allow a `Host:` header (thus this may be the point for 'first'), it only became (semi) mandatory with HTTP 1.1 - and thus browsers sending a `Host:` field with every request. For some easy overview see [here](https://medium.com/platform-engineer/evolution-of-http-69cfe6531ba0)